# AMCharts 4 keypress event not firing

Tags: javascript, amcharts4

Even though [AMCharts 4 class documentation](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/chart/#Events) lists the event of keypress or keydown, when I add these to the list of events in the chart json configuration these never fire. I tried clicking on the chart for it to have focus (as some solutions pointed out) but nothing every happens.

Comment: Can you please share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can reproduce your issue?